# tns preview works but tns build android --bundle

Tags: android, angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I have created few components with `NativeScript/Angular` and working as expected with `tns preview`.

When I build it with `tns build android --bundle`, it builds `.apk` but when Install and open on my mobile few of options not working such as `ActionBar title`, `auto complete` etc..

Should I follow any another step to make apk?

Comment: no. You can try to run "tns run android --bundle" and check console messages.

Comment: It leads me to active devices not found error. I have created everything but still getting this error. Thats why I used tns preview.

Answer (score 0):

Yes try to use this command for build new apk:-

tns build android --bundle --env.uglify --env.*